# Сменить style.css на свой при загрузке страницы

Tags: android, webview, css

В общем хочу поменять css  в html файле. Делаю гет запрос на сервер и перед отображением юзеру надо изменить style.css

Comment: @mesteruh,  Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. **КОД**

Comment: я сделал загрузку сайта в webview как в статье http://habrahabr.ru/post/117885/. Мне понадобилось изменить разметку. Вручную делать очень долго(2000 строк в css файле)

Answer (score 1):

Получаем `HTML` код страницы, которую хотим загрузить:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
    sb.append(line + "\n");

String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

is.close(); // Close the stream
```

Дальше парсим строку resString в поисках нужного нам CSS, заменяем на тот, который надо, и загружаем строку в WebView:

```
webView.loadData(resString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

если нужно полностью style.css поменять тогда

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("my.css")) {
                try {
                    return new WebResourceResponse("text/css", "UTF-8", getAssets().open("new.css"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    });
}
```

А если css определенного блока, тогда уже либо парсить и регуляркой заменять, либо через js, но лучше менять css полностью.